# How to force loading of libraries to make reproducible code in R?

Tags: r, r-caret

I am designing an experiment where I will be setting the seed initially using `set.seed()` and executing a number of functions that load required libraries. I plan to run the same code on multiple machines with different seed values.

On doing a few preliminary tests, I was surprised that I could not reproduce the results in the **same session** (of course I did not realize at that point that the session was the culprit). After trying all sorts of debugging I finally found that that loading certain libraries in R modifies the `.Random.seed`, for example executing the following code in a **new session**

```
set.seed(123)
sample(1000, 3)

set.seed(123)
require("caret")
sample(1000, 3)

set.seed(123)
require("caret")
sample(1000, 3)
```

The results of the `sample` statement are

```
288 788 409
409 883 939
288 788 409
```

I was expecting the second and third `sample` statement to produce the same sequence.

Is there any way to force the loading of libraries in R so that I can reproduce the results without remembering to restart the session every time? Also is it mentioned anywhere in documentation that `caret` modifies the seed when it is loaded?

Comment: Why don't you first load all necessary packages and then set the seed?

Comment: I considered that option, but then every time I modify my functions with new libraries, I will have to remember to add them in the main script. And I kind of like to keep my code compact and load libraries where required.

Comment: You could create an extra script which loads all libraries, which is sourced in the beginning of your main script. Code stays compact, however libraries are loaded at the beginning, not where required.

Comment: Thanks, I found a workaround using the following,
    if(! (length(sessionInfo()$basePkgs) == 7)) 
        stop("To reproduceable examples, start in a new session")
This way I will be reminded to start a new session every time. I will leave the question open as this does not answer how to force load of library

Comment: I don't get exactly what you are asking. Are you looking for a way to R to load some libraries without telling it to do so? How can R possibly load libraries if nor `library` nor `require` is called somewhere? Anyway, it appears that for some reason while loading `caret` R draw a random number. Instead of `sample()` in your line, try `runif(100)` and you'll see that the result is the same starting from the second element.

Comment: @nicola : What I want to know is how can I force R to load a library so that each time `require(caret)` is called R will draw a random number and not just the first time.